# How to play live stream on android?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I create one html5 app which can play http live stream on ios , and i also need to play tv stream on android. I want to know need I use http dynamic streaming or http live stream, which is better ?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](http://quitenoteworthy.blogspot.com/2011/03/http-live-streaming-and-android.html) android 3.0 honeycomb supports HTTP live streaming or "HLS" which would probably be your best option while using a server technology like Wowza.